# Firebase - use two authentication providers for same user

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

For a Firebase project containing two different applications, i need to activate two different authentication providers on the Firebase users.
Currently i am able to set (via console) Google login provider **OR** mail/password provider, but never both on the same user.

Funny part is one of the users (a developer with console access) has been able to enable it, so there must be a way, but we can't figure out how he did it. See the user with both providers in the screenshot below.

[image: current users on firebase]

current auth methods:

[image: auth methods]

EDIT 14/10/2018

The "one account per email address" setting was disabled. No luck.
We tried this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking

but it seems we cannot make it work with node js.

The third option suggested in the comments (use different projects for different apps) cannot be followed, as these are actually two related apps with some common components.

after some troubleshooting i'm afraid i will just add some more weird stuff:
1) With the option "one account per email address" disabled, i tried to delete my account then add it again with email\password, this succeded. Then i tried to login with google in the app: the login failed but in firebase i was able to see a new "empty" (no email) user, with a new UID.
THEN i deleted all the accounts and tried to login with google in the app (normally it creates the account in firebase), result: login failed, empty account created. Deleted it, tried to create it manually on the console, result: "account already existing".

So after this we just gave up and went for a different way to handle the authentication. Hope to find this working in the future, as it could be really useful for us.

Comment: you think that it is a bug in firebase authentication?

Answer (score 2):

> Currently i am able to set (via console) Google login provider OR mail/password provider, but never both on the same user.

It sounds like you have the setting <kbd>One account per email address</kbd> enabled (which is the default). When this is enabled, there can be only a single account per email address. So if a user signed in with email+password first, and then that user tries to sign in with their Google account for the same email, the second login gets rejected. This is the expected behavior for this setting, and is meant to prevent one user from getting multiple accounts.

The recommended approach to support users signing in with multiple providers is to link their email+password and Google accounts together as shown in the [documentation on linking accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking).

So you will have to pick one of these options:

1. Disable the "One account per email address" setting in the [Sign-in method screen](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/providers).
2. Enable account linking, which is the preferred approach if this is indeed a single user signing in with two providers.
3. Use a separate project for each app, which is the preferred approach if the apps are unrelated, or will be perceived by the user as being separate apps. For example: if you have an regular app and an app for admin users, those should be on the same project. But if you have two different games, they should not be using the same project.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for all available auth method. But at the usage, when a user signed up with one provider, then he/she can try to sign in/up another provider. If existing user then you should `link` the credential to existing account with :

```
auth.currentUser.linkWithPopup(provider).then((result)=>{
    var user = result.user 
}).catch((error)=> {
   // Handle Errors here.
   // ...
});
```

for more information [available](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) here

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done by with:

```
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().currentUser.linkWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
      var credential = result.credential;
      var user = result.user;
    }).catch(function(error){
    });
  }
```

After logging in with email, another button could be used to link accounts through by using `onclick="linkWithPopup()"` this creat a popup box allowing the user to link in with another another account/provider.
You'd see the changes in firebase, I hope it is helpfull.